# ImportError when importing backwards

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, importerror

When I try to import backward (example coming), I get an ImportError.

Let's say I have 3 python files: modA.py, modB.py, and modC.py

```
dir/
    modA.py
    modB.py
    modC.py
```

modA.py:

```
import modB

instB = modB.clsB()

print("Successful")
```

modB.py:

```
import modC

list = [modC.clsC]

class clsB:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

modC.py

```
from modB import clsB

instB = clsB()

class clsC(clsB):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

I can import each individually, but when modC trys to import modB, it gives an error for some reason. Is there any way around this error, or is it not possible to backward import (or whatever the correct term is)?

Comment: I would define clsC in another file which they both import. Recursive imports aren't very good practice

Comment: You are trying to use circular imports. This is bad. Just re-organize your module structure to avoidthis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice how `modB` imports `modC`. This causes infinite imports, which is of course, a bad thing. You're clearly trying to use class inheritance, but the way it's set up, classes are inheriting from themselves. You might want to reconsider the flow of everything, and possibly merging the scripts into one file

Comment: Thank you. I figured that imports were causing some sort of problem like this, but couldn't find a proper explanation of what was going on. I have made the edits suggested and fixed it.